# UIScrollView touches don't seem to work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I used the "View-based Application" template in Xcode for an iPhone project and went into the view controller's XIB.

I changed the view from a basic `UIView` to a `UIScrollView`, and now the method

`(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;`

never gets called. I have an `NSLog` statement in there. It gets called just fine when the controller's view is a `UIView`, so what's different/special about `UIScrollView`s that you don't receive touch events? How can I respond to a touch event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIScrollView does not pass on all touch events. It does this because it tries to interpret swipe and scroll gestures itself.

Have a look at this thread: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=7519817 to learn about UIScrollView and events. The bottom line is that you can handle events in your view's `-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)aTouches withEvent:(UIEvent *)anEvent` but it's not straight forward.

I have personally seen some funkyness in UIScollView's effect on hit testing sub views.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any direct experience here, but I was looking over documentation that might explain this yesterday. I think you'll find that `UIScrollView` captures touches in order to handle its scrolling. Take a look at `delaysContentTouches` in the documentation window.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a custom content subview, then implement touchesEnded:withEvent: in that view.  You'll get all the taps you want!